# Size of / partition?

Tags: hard-drive, root, home-directory

So, I decided I really need a seperate /home, since I never upgrade Ubuntu and always do a clean install etc, and I'm getting to a point where my data is becoming WAY too large for simple backups.

Right now I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed and I'm going to create a partition inside there and then probably just copy the current home to the new and set mount point.
The thing is though, I'm having to do a big spring clean since I have 100Gig left of a 500Gig HDD, but have absolutely no idea how much of that is taken up by / and how much would be taken up by my /home.

So my question is this.

I want to ensure that I make my new /home big enough to house all my data, but have PLENTY of room for root files if I install new apps etc.

So, my question I guess is, how much room should I leave for / to ensure I won't have to worry at all about installing new apps?

Comment: I did the same but also use a small home and use symlinks to point to directories on my 2nd disc). 15 Gb root and 10 Gb home for me is more than enough. Mind you: if you run low in /home you can always symlink a directory to a 2nd disc.

Comment: That's actually a really good point about the syslink, never thought about that, thanks very much!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/167686/appropriate-size-for-root-partition